# How to wait some seconds before doing something in OnMouseUp Event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a game with some animations, and use those animations when the user clicks on a button. I would like to show the user the animation, and not "just" call a new level with Application.loadLevel. I thought I could use the Time.DeltaTime in the onMouseUp method and add it to a predefined 0f value, then check if it is bigger than (for example) 1f, but it just won't work as the onMouseUp method adds just "it's own time" as the delta time.

My script looks like this now:

```
public class ClickScriptAnim : MonoBehaviour {

public Sprite pressedBtn;
public Sprite btn; 
public GameObject target;
public string message;
public Transform mesh;
private bool inAnim = true;
private Animator animator;
private float inGameTime = 0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    animator = mesh.GetComponent<Animator>();
}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnMouseDown() {
    animator.SetBool("callAnim", true);

}

void OnMouseUp() {
    animator.SetBool("callAnim", false);
    animator.SetBool("callGoAway", true);
    float animTime = Time.deltaTime;

    Debug.Log(inGameTime.ToString());
// I would like to put here something to wait some seconds
        target.SendMessage(message, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep(1000) will wait a second, are you looking for something along these line?

Comment: Where is that code you tried to wait some time?

Comment: As I have written, I tried to put a inGameTime += Time.deltaTime to the onMouseUp() method, but it doesn't work as intended because the  OnMouseUp method returns just a minimal deltaTime

Comment: You don't want to wait while processing user input. If you want animation to be delayed, then why not use animation which does nothing (for some number of frames) when started?

Answer (score 1):

Im not entirely sure what your trying to do by using Time.deltaTime in onMouseUp. This is just the time in seconds since the last frame was rendered, and should act the same no matter where you try to access it. Normally it is used in a function that is called every frame, not one-off events like onMouseUp.

Despite not being certain what you are trying to achieve, it sounds like you should be using Invoke:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

Just put the code you wish to be delayed into a separate function, and then invoke that function with a delay in onMouseUp.

EDIT: To backup what some others have said here I would not use Thread.Sleep() in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this (and all waiting functions that do not appear to make the game "freeze") by blocking the `Update` loop by using a `Coroutine`.

Here is a sample of what you are probably looking for.

```
void OnMouseUp() 
{
    animator.SetBool("callAnim", false);
    animator.SetBool("callGoAway", true);

    //Removed the assignement of Time.deltaTime as it did nothing for you...

    StartCoroutine(DelayedCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator DoSomethingAfterDelay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); // The parameter is the number of seconds to wait
    target.SendMessage(message, SendMessageOptions.RequireReceiver);
}
```

Based on your example it is difficult to determine exactly *what you want to accomplish* but the above example is the "correct" way to do something after a delay in Unity 3D.  If you wanted to delay your animation, simply place the calling code in the Coroutine as I did the `SendMessage` invocation.

The coroutine is launched on it's own special game loop that is somewhat concurrent to your game's `Update` loop.  These are very useful for many different things and offer a type of "threading" (albeit not real threading).

**NOTE**:
Do NOT use `Thread.Sleep()` in Unity, it will literally freeze the game loop and could cause a crash if done at a bad time.  Unity games run on a single thread that handles all of the lifecycle events (`Awake()`, `Start()`, `Update()`, etc...).  Calling `Thread.Sleep()` will stop the execution of these events until it returns and is most likely NOT what you're looking for as it will appear that the game has frozen and cause a bad user experience.